# Multidimensional databinding? How to?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Im trying to create a set of grids and add them to a scrollview.

Here is what it should look like:
http://tinypic.com/r/256gpxf/7

The "depatures" showing up under "other stop" should be dynamic. I know how to create the titles ("other stop") using databinding but i need to get the depatures for each stop. It's like a databinding in a databinding of some kind.

It's hard to explain but if you look at the screenshot i think you guys can figure out what i mean :)

**EDIT:**

The class for busstops:

```
public class BusStop
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string ID { get; private set; }
        public List<Depature> Depatures { get; private set; }

        public BusStop(string name, string id)
        {
            Name = name;
            ID = id;
            Depatures = new List<Depature>();
        }
    }
```

Depature class:

```
public class Depature
    {

        public string Destination { get; private set; }
        public int Next { get; private set; }
        public int NextNext { get; private set; }

        public Depature(string destination, int next, int nextNext)
        {
            Destination = destination;
            Next = next;
            NextNext = nextNext;
        }
    }
```

Each stop has a diffrent set of depatures attached to it. That's what im trying to populate in a grid. One grid for each stop. Here is "static" sample xaml for a stop with 4 depatures:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,12">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="42" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="38" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="32" Text="Other Stop" Foreground="#FFE37306" />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" Text="avgår"/>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12" Text="nästa"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikGridLine}" Background="#0D4774">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikTextLine}" Text="80" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="6,0,12,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nils Eriksson Term" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Text="5" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Text="15" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikGridLine}" Background="#0D4774">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikTextLine}" Text="80" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="6,0,12,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nils Eriksson Term" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Text="5" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Text="15" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikGridLine}" Background="#0D4774">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikTextLine}" Text="80" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="6,0,12,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nils Eriksson Term" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Text="5" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Text="15" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikGridLine}" Background="#0D4774">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikTextLine}" Text="80" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="6,0,12,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nils Eriksson Term" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Text="5" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Text="15" />
</Grid>
```

Is using a grid even a good idea? It seems like i have to define each row with rowdefinitions etc.

Thanks in advance!

/R

Comment: not sure to understand... but let me try : you have a two level hierachy of objects ? If true, "simply" use a ItemsControl bound to the first level level, and add a datatemplate with another itemscontrol bound the 2nd level of objects... Can you paste your OM code to help me understand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Now that you posted your code i adjusted the template. You misspelled "Departures" by the way, it's missing an "r".

Sample data i use:

```
        List<BusStop> data = new List<BusStop>();
        BusStop busStop1 = new BusStop("Some Stop", "123");
        busStop1.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop1.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop1.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop1.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        BusStop busStop2 = new BusStop("Other Stop", "42");
        busStop2.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop2.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop2.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        busStop2.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Nils Eriksson Term", 5, 15));
        BusStop busStop3 = new BusStop("Not A Stop", "0");
        busStop3.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Void", 5, 15));
        busStop3.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Void", 5, 15));
        busStop3.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Void", 5, 15));
        busStop3.Depatures.Add(new Depature("Void", 5, 15));
        data.Add(busStop1);
        data.Add(busStop2);
        data.Add(busStop3);
        Data = data;
```

The general approach should be to define nested `DataTemplates`, here i use a `ItemsControl` whose `ItemTemplate` contains headers and another `ItemsControl`:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="38" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Children>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="32" Foreground="#FFE37306"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="12" Text="avgår"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="12" Text="nästa"/>
                        </Grid.Children>
                    </Grid>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Depatures}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="38" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.Children>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikGridLine}" Background="#0D4774">
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="80" Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikTextLine}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Destination}" Foreground="DarkBlue"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Next}"     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Foreground="DarkBlue"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding NextNext}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Foreground="DarkBlue"/>
                                    </Grid.Children>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Looks something like this (it's lacking your specific styles and overrides of course):
[image: A Picture]

You still did not specify where your three different blocks come from etc. but anything beyond this is definitely your problem...

Comment: +1 Because it does provide a good guide to the solution. However the question is tagged Silverlight and Windows-Phone-7, there is no `IsSharedSizeScope` in Silverlight. Seeing as its a WP7 app more perscriptive sizing is acceptable since there are only a few form factors of WP7 devices.

Comment: Oh, i did not know that... (i have not done anything in Silverlight so far, so i do not know all the differences)

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thanks a million for the answer (and for the spelling tip) :)